# Display basic HTML file in NodeJS and ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express

I am using NodeJS and ExpressJS to implement a RESTful API server for a simple backend.  I am also using BackboneJS to render views in the front. Therefore, right now I have a single index.html file that I want to render when the client sends a /GET to the '/' route. This is what I have so far:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.bodyParser());
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Server = mongo.Server, 
    DB = mongo.Db,
    BSON = mongo.BSONPure;

var server = new Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true});


db = new DB('mydb', server, {safe: true});

db.open(function(err, db) {
    if(!err) {
        console.log("Connected to 'mydb' database");
        db.collection('items', {safe:true}, function(err, collection) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Creating collection 'items'");
            }
        });
    }
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.engine('.html');

var listItems = function(req, res){
    db.collection('items', function(err, collection){
        var items = collection.find();
        console.log(items);
        res.send(items);
    });
}

var itemDetails = function(req, res){

}

var deleteItem = function(req, res){

}

var createItem = function(req, res){

}

var updateItem = function(req, res){

}

var routeHome = function(req, res){

        // What can I do here to render a plain .html file?

}

app.all('*', function(req, res, next){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    res.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
    next();
});

app.get('/', routeHome);

app.get('/items', listItems);
app.get('/items/:id', itemDetails);
app.del('/users/:id', deleteItem);
app.post('/users', createItem);
app.put('/users/:id', updateItem);

app.listen(port);

console.log("Server started up on port " + port);
```

As you can see I have everything set up except I cannot figure out how to send a regular .html file to the client. I do not need a rendering engine because Backbone is doing all that for me. I just want to get index.html to go to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just using the `express.static` middleware? Since you're using Backbone, you might have the need for sending static JS files as well:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

Place that somewhere before your other routes. It will try and find files requested in `__dirname` (the directory where your app.js file resides, but you can of course change the location where the middleware will try and find files), including `index.html`.

Comment: so what would I put in my app.get() call back function to send that file back to the client?

Comment: Nothing, you can even remove it :)

Comment: so what you have done above will allow a GET to '/' (the root of my site) to render index.html automatically?

Comment: Correct. And also any js/css files you might want to load from your index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Step One, Remove `app.engine(".html")`,

Step Two:

```
var routeHome = function(req, res){
    // Do What Ever
    res.sendFile("index.html",function(err){ // Transfer The File With COntent Type Text/HTML
        if(err){
            res.end("Sorry, Error.");
        }else{
            res.end(); // Send The Response
        }
    })
}
```